# Regular Expression to capture numbers in parentheses

Tags: regex

I tried searching for this but couldn't find a similar question.

I have a string that looks like the following:

> Products Ran (14, 51, 71, 92) at 2012-07-05

I want to only grab the numbers that are inside the parentheses, so that I have the following matches:

> 14 51 71 92

I've tried the following, but am obviously missing something:

```
(?x)
(?<=\()            #Opening parentheses
(?<product>\d*)    #Group the numbers
(?=\))             #Closing parentheses
```

---

Came up with the following as the solution:

```
(?<=\([^\)]*)\d+(?=[^\(]*\))
```

Comment: Please specify which tool/language/regex engine you are using when posting regex questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ridgerunner. I'm using C#/.NET Framework for the Regex.  
I have been using http://regexhero.net/tester/ to test out my expressions, since it uses Silverylight, whichs runs on the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regex `(?<=\(.*)(\d+)(?=.*\))`

Comment: This seems to work! Looks like I just needed to include all characters inside of the parentheses inside of my lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: Unfortunately, `(?<=\(.*)(\d+)(?=.*\))` erroneously matches the `4` in the target string: "`before 1 (2, 3) middle 4  (5, 6) after 7`"

Comment: Good point ridgerunner, however, I'm ok with this since I won't have any strings that have more than one set of open/close parentheses.

Comment: @ridgerunner Your comment made me curious as to how to overcome that problem, and I managed to come up with a solution:
(?<=\([^\)]*)\d+(?=[^\(]*\))
Thanks for pointing out that problem.